# Solve the given PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Solve the Partial Differential equation: 
$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial }{\partial r}\big(r\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\big) $$
for $r \in [0,1]$ and $t \gt 0$, with the initial condition $u(r,0)=g(r), \text{ and boundary condition } u(1,t)=0.$

**My Approach**

Rewriting the pde we get:
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} =\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial r^2}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial u}{\partial r} $$

Let $u(r,t)= R(r)T(t)$, be the solution of the given pde, which reduces the pde:$$rR''+R'-\lambda rR=0, T'-\lambda T=0$$, which can be reduced to Strum-Livouille problem $-(-rR')'=\lambda rR$, my question is how to find the function $R(r)$?

Is my approach right?- Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It is $u(r,t)=R(r)T(t).$

Comment: Yes, your approach is right up to this point.

Comment: Any help on how to choose $\lambda$?

Comment: Express $R$ as a power series in terms of $r$. You should get Bessel functions.

Comment: It is not in the the Bessel's equation form @player100

Comment: $R(r)$ is not *a* Bessel function.  It is a (non-simple) combination of $K_0(r\sqrt{\lambda})$ and $I_0(r\sqrt{\lambda})$, which already suggests a constraint on $\lambda$ (since you expect $R(r)$ is real valued).  (This combination can also be written as a non-simple combination of $J_0$ and $Y_0$.)

Comment: It is a standard Bessel equation if you let $\lambda < 0$. Otherwise you have a modified Bessel equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is correct but far to lead to the result. As already pointed out in the comments, one can express $R(r)$ in terms of Bessel functions :
$$R(r)=c_1J_0(\sqrt{-\lambda}\:\:r)+c_2Y_0(\sqrt{-\lambda}\:\:r)\qquad\text{if}\quad \lambda<0$$
$$R(r)=c_1I_0(\sqrt{\lambda}\:\:r)+c_2K_0(\sqrt{\lambda}\:\:r)\qquad\text{if}\quad \lambda>0$$
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunctionoftheSecondKind.html

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheSecondKind.html

Then you get some particular solutions of the PDE, but not a particular solution fitting the condition $u(r,0)=g(r)$ where $g(r)$ is a given function which is not necessarily a Bessel function of the above kind.

A more general solution of the PDE can be (for exqample in case $\lambda<0$) on the form :
$$u(x,t)=\sum_{\lambda}\left(f_1(\lambda)I_0(\sqrt{\lambda}\:\:r)+f_2(\lambda)K_0(\sqrt{\lambda}\:\:r)\right)e^{\lambda t}$$
With condition $g(r)=\sum_{\lambda}\left(f_1(\lambda)I_0(\sqrt{\lambda}\:\:r)+f_2(\lambda)K_0(\sqrt{\lambda}\:\:r)\right)$

$f_1(\lambda)$ and $f_2(\lambda)$ have to be determined in order t0 fit $g(r)$.

The difficulty is to expend the given fonction $g(r)$ into series of Bessel functions. This is a problem similar to the expansion into Fourier series of sinusoidal functions, but more arduous. One can find relevant papers on the web with key words "Neumann Bessel series" or "Fourier Bessel series". For example : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Fourier-BesselSeries.html . Good luck!